# Append to PDF file with convert in bash

Tags: image, bash, append

I'm basically downloading some images from a website using **wget** to then append them into a PDF file using the command line program "convert". But this last thing seems not to work.

I'm getting all the .jpg images and storing them into one folder with no problems, but when I try to merge them into the PDF file, it always reminds with the last appended image. I've read of the convert's *-append* argument, but it still won't work.

This is how my code looks like:

```
for file in *.jpg
do
    convert "${file}" -append "myfile.pdf"  

done
```

But as logical as it seems, **myfile.pdf** always ends up having only the last jpg appended image. 
I know that using convert like:

```
convert img1.jpg img2.jpg img3.jpg myfile.pdf
```

Would do the trick. But as I don't know how many images will I have in the download directory, I cannot hardcode the arguments, so I guess a loop for each image in that directory as I'm trying would be the best solution.

Does anybody know how to achieve my goal? Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` automatically expands wildcard arguments (unless if they are quoted or escaped) so even if `convert` does not support wildcard expansion, `bash` does. So you could just do

```
convert *.jpg myfile.pdf
```

note that if there are too many files, this can result with "arglist too long". But that should be OK for several hundred files.

Comment: Thanks! Really great information! Worked like charm!

Comment: too many years of MS-DOS non-expanding shell almost got the best of you :)

Answer (score 0):

If your file name follows a pattern like `img1.jpg img2.jpg .....` . Then you may also use bash range:

```
convert img{1..5}.jpg
```

this will work for `img1.jpg img2.jpg img3.jpg img4.jpg img5.jpg` . You can change your range as per your requirement.

For converting all the `jpg` files , answer is already present in other answer by @Jean-François Fabre.